# как в Active Directory ограничить вход одному пользователь к 1 серверу

Tags: windows, сервер

как в Active Directory ограничить вход одному пользователь к 1 серверу  из всех серверов домена? домен развернут на windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 3):

Запустите оснастку ADUC (Active Directory Users and Computers), выполнив команду dsa.msc.
С помощью поиска найдите учетную запись пользователя, которому нужно разрешить вход только на определённые компьютеры и откройте его свойства.
Перейдите на вкладку Account и нажмите кнопку Log On To
выбрать опцию The following computers и добавьте в список имена компьютеров, но которые ему разрешено логиниться.